# Add cheerio-based search loop to node-simplecrawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I am crawling a website with [node-simplecrawler](https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler) and I need to search for certain attribute values in a certain divs on each page.

The simplecrawler docs suggest the following structure for such task:

```
myCrawler.on("fetchcomplete",function(queueItem,data,res) {
  var continue = this.wait();
  doSomeDiscovery(data,function(foundURLs){
    foundURLs.forEach(crawler.queueURL.bind(crawler));
    continue();
  });
});
```

I tried and tried, but can't figure out where exactly and how to insert my piece of Cheerio-based search code into that structure. Would really really appreciate some help here.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
$('div#jsid-post-container').each(function(i, element){
var StuffINeedToFetch = $(this).attr('data-external-id').text;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually was no need to mess with doSomeDiscovery. Solution is to work with responseBuffer contents directly:

```
myCrawler.on("fetchcomplete",function(queueItem, responseBuffer){
    html = responseBuffer.toString();
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('div#jsid-post-container').each(function(i, element){
    var StuffINeedToFetch = $(this).attr('data-external-id').text;
});
```

Comment: body = responseBuffer.toString(); should be var html =